# Posicionamento com imageView

Tags: android, imageview

preciso posicionar as imagens no layout, porém não estou sabendo como posicionar estas imagens usando o ImageView no android. Gostaria que o layout ficasse como o da imagem abaixo, mas não fica. Todos ficam na mesma linha e alguns até nao aparecem. Alguém poderia dar uma ajuda de como poderia fazer este layout?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Consulte o GridView https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você deve usar o [GridView](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html), ele monta como se fosse uma tabela com cada imagem em uma coluna.

Exemplo do XML:

```
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/gridview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:columnWidth="90dp"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:gravity="center"
/>
```

Exemplo do Java:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
    gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

    gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(HelloGridView.this, "" + position,
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

Exemplo do **ImageAdapter**

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;

    public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return mThumbIds.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    // create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView;
        if (convertView == null) {
            // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
            imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
        } else {
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        }

        imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
        return imageView;
    }

    // references to our images
    private Integer[] mThumbIds = {
            R.drawable.sample_2, R.drawable.sample_3,
            R.drawable.sample_4, R.drawable.sample_5,
            R.drawable.sample_6, R.drawable.sample_7,
            R.drawable.sample_0, R.drawable.sample_1,
            R.drawable.sample_2, R.drawable.sample_3,
            R.drawable.sample_4, R.drawable.sample_5,
            R.drawable.sample_6, R.drawable.sample_7,
            R.drawable.sample_0, R.drawable.sample_1,
            R.drawable.sample_2, R.drawable.sample_3,
            R.drawable.sample_4, R.drawable.sample_5,
            R.drawable.sample_6, R.drawable.sample_7
    };
}
```

Comment: Com a classe ImageAdapter, eu poderia esta mesma classe para apresentar imagens diferentes em outras Activitys?

Comment: O problema fica no array *mThumbIds* que vai puxar sempre essas imagens, pra solucionar isso você pode receber o array das imagens como parâmetro no adapter, ai você pode usá-lo em diferentes ocasiões, cada vez que chamá-lo de uma activity diferente, vai vir um array de imagens diferente.

Comment: Ok...vou fazer isso então

Comment: Blz, se tiver dificuldades com o código da um toque pra gente aqui